# Does canvas support floating point numbers when drawing line or arc?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

In the canvas element, are floating point numbers actually treated as floats by the `lineTo` and `arc` methods?

**For example:**

```js
context.moveTo(20.4562, 80.8923);
context.lineTo(120.1123, 90.2134);
context.arc(24.5113, 36.7989, 20.123, 0, Math.PI*2);
```

Does canvas really support float number coordinates, or it just converting the float numbers to integers when drawing line, arc, rect, etc.?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A bitmap does not support floating point values on its own. It can only deal with integer values. The 2D context of the canvas deals mostly with *paths* which is per-SE not connected to the bitmap.

Paths are arbitrary and exists only as vectors internally. It's when they are stroked or filled they are put through a *rasterizing* process, ie. converted to a bitmap representation.

Paths and their assigned points in the bitmap can themselves hold fraction values, but a bitmap can't. However, it is possible to represent a fractional value using *interpolation* (sub-pixeling) which gives the impression of having a larger available bitmap resolution, which in turn removes the jaggy look if values where cut down to just integers.

(And resolution is the main point of doing interpolation. A screen is about the equivalent of 72-96 DPI. If the screen had a higher resolution, 300+ DPI, interpolation would not be needed, as is in the case with printing. But we are there now and drawings would look jaggy if interpolation wasn't used as a compensation for lack of resolution).

## Here is how it works

When a pixel lands on a integer bound value, it is a simple case of setting the pixel to that value.

[image: int]

When you deal with a floating point there is no where to set a pixel in part, it has to be either be rounded down (floor'ed) or placed in the next cell (ceil'ed), ie. 3.2 becomes 3, 3.7 becomes 4 etc.

[image: intvsfloat]

## Interpolation / sub-pixeling

However, someone came up with the idea some decades ago to represent the fractional part as a blend between the actual pixel and the next pixel.

If the pixel value was 3.5, the fractional part would represent here 50% of black and 50% of white. It would still occupy a whole pixel cell, but since it is so tiny it will appear to just occupy a fraction of its cell thanks to the surrounding pixels which contribute to the illusion.

So in this case the last pixel set wold look like this:

[image: subpixel 50%]

In case the value was 3.25, only 25% of the remaining pixel would be mixed, making the last pixel look like:

[image: subpixel 25%]

This will apply to all pixels that would land on a fractional value. When you draw a diagonal line and some points "crosses" two pixels, a mix of those will be applied to the closed integer based placement, making the line look smooth.

Now, in case of canvas the shapes are interpolated with the alpha channel. Then the shape is blended and composited using Porter-Duff with the existing content, which is what we see as the final result.

This is also something to have in mind in regards to performance. If interpolation is needed the cost goes up, as for each pixel the browser (or sub-system) has to calculate the fractional representation. For this reason you could make sure to use integer values by rounding them off before passing them to the path method. This is of course not doable with arcs, ellipses, diagonal lines at some degrees etc., but it can help speed up things in some cases.

This is the principle with interpolation which applies when fractional coordinates are used. However, there are more complex ways of interpolate and sub-pixel. In modern world 2x2 or 4x4 sampling is more common to give a more accurate result.

## Demo

If we make a small zoomed in line we can see the end of the line "fade" in and out when we variate the fraction value.

This line is 3 pixels wide, then we add a fraction value between [0, 1] to it and we can see the last ceil'ed pixel is being resampled:

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    x = 3.1, dx = 0.1;

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.font = "14px sans-serif";

(function loop() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,350,50);
  ctx.fillRect(0,0, x, 1); // forces pixel-alignment for demo

  ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas, 0,0,4,1, 0, 0, 200, 50);
  
  x += dx;
  if (x <= 3 || x >= 4) dx = -dx;

  info(x);
  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "length: " + x.toFixed(2);
  
  setTimeout(loop, 160)
})();

function info(x) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";

  ctx.fillText("Perceived length", 210, 19);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 15, x * 50, 2);
  ctx.fillRect(x*50-1, 12, 2, 7);

  x = x === 3 ? 3 : 4;
  ctx.fillText("Actual length", 210, 40);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 35, x * 50, 2);
  ctx.fillRect(x*50-1, 32, 2, 7);
}
```

```css
div {font:bold 14px sans-serif}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=50></canvas><br>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The screen device is a pixel device, so finally any drawing is mapped to the whole pixels, i.e. integers. However, using of floating point coordinates instead of integer in HTML5 canvas does change the result.

If you draw with coordinates that are not integers, it automatically uses anti-aliasing to try to smooth out the lines. You can see an example in [this article](http://seb.ly/2011/02/html5-canvas-sprite-optimisation/).

It also affects on `drawImage`, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114205/drawing-images-on-html5-canvas-at-floating-point-coordinates) for more details.

Note, that use of floating point coordinates has a significant performance penalty.

Comment: Incorrect ... (1) Modern devices have sub-pixel resolution and canvas does not map its drawings to whole integers, (2) JavaScript itself natively uses floats and canvas uses floats too so using floats does not change the result.  (3) Canvas will *always use antialiasing* to smooth out paths (4) Using floats does not have a performance penalty as JS uses floats natively.

Comment: @markE actually.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Optimizing_canvas#:~:text=This%20forces%20the%20browser%20to%20do%20extra%20calculations%20to%20create%20the%20anti%2Daliasing%20effect.%20To%20avoid%20this%2C%20make%20sure%20to%20round%20all%20co%2Dordinates%20used%20in%20calls%20to%20drawImage()%20using%20Math.floor()%2C%20for%20example.